# Using Promise.all with loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

In my code, I want to compare arrays and delete files on the server that do not match in arrays. Since unlink is an asynchronous operation, I decided to use the async await. But I'm not sure if I did everything right. Do I need to wrap everything in the Promise.all or remove it altogether

```
oldFiles.map(async (oldFile) => {
  await Promise.all(
    editedFiles.map(async (editedFile, index) => {
      if (oldFile === editedFile) {
        return;
      }
      //delete file if it the last editedFile that has no overlap with oldFile
      if (index === editedFiles.length - 1) {
        await unlink(`${filesDir}/${oldFile}`);
      }
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: The logic here is quite confusing. You're deleting from `oldFiles` but how exactly should they be filtered by `editedFiles`? And what's the logic around the _last edited file_? It might be clearer if you [edit] your question with the logic explained in plain words instead of trying to decipher your code

Comment: Could you also please provide some sample data showing both arrays and which entries from `oldFiles` should be deleted

Comment: What problem do you want help with?  If you want to know when `oldFiles.map()` is done, you will have to use an outer `Promise.all()`.

Comment: The reason for using `promise.all()` was just to make `unlink` run in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like a better solution would be to filter `oldFiles` for any `editedFiles` then create an array of *unlink* promises to wait on

```js
const editedFilesHash = new Set(editedFiles); // makes for faster lookups

await Promise.all(
  oldFiles
    .filter((oldFile) => !editedFilesHash.has(oldFile))
    .map((oldFile) => unlink(`${filesDir}/${oldFile}`))
);
```

It was totally unclear what the *last index check* was for and it seemed completely unnecessary to the overall logic.

Comment: Well, I ended up with quite imperative code with a nested loop in which I returned from the inner loop in the case when the files did not match for comparison with the next `oldFile` and `index === editedFiles.length - 1` check meant that this was the last `editedFile` from `editedFiles` and none of `editedFiles` matched `oldFile`